# Sum up a calculated column's values for each user in Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I've been looking around for quite some time, and I'm not entirely sure how to accomplish this in Sharepoint 2007.

I'm trying to create a web part view that takes the entries of a particular data source, groups the entries by the user, and then sums up a calculated column from said source.

I've found similar tutorials online about creating the web part views and making calculated columns; however, I can't figure out how to sum up the columns for each user listed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a List View Web Part, modify your view by selecting "Modify this view" in the view-picker (drop down list at the top right of the web part).

On the view settings page, expand the Group By section and specify which column(s) you will group by. Expand the Totals section and select which aggregations you want to perform on which columns.

Click OK.

The results are overall totals at the top of the column, and group totals above each group.

Comment: While that works exactly for your standard column, it doesn't list any custom calculated columns. Tutorials have instructed how to do this in Sharepoint designer; however, none of them have included the option of grouping together the results by a particular column.

Comment: @bayphillips: Ah, I take your point. Have you considered linking the list to Access or exporting to Excel, then reporting from your data using those tools. It's wicked what can be accomplished with SharePoint data in an Excel pivot table.

Comment: Do you need Excel services for that?

Comment: @bayphillips: Nope. Excel services will help you display the spreadsheet in the browser; however, you can export to a regular Excel spreadsheet from the Actions menu on the list, if you have adequate permissions.